# how to fix this type error in python 3.0 ? whenever i use passing argument(dict{}) it shows this type of error "NameError: name 'P' is not defined"

Tags: python-3.x

```
 def bowling(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5):
        x=1
        while x<6:
            print(px.get('role'))
```

"NameError: name 'P' is not defined"

```
 x=x+1
 p1={'name':'Virat Kohli', 'role':'bat', 'runs':112, '4':10, '6':0, 'balls':119, 'field':0}
 p2={'name':'du Plessis', 'role':'bat', 'runs':120, '4':11, '6':2, 'balls':112, 'field':0}
 p3={'name':'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':1, 'overs':10, 'runs':71, 'field':1}
 p4={'name':'Yuzvendra Chahal', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':2, 'overs':10, 'runs':45, 'field':0}
 p5={'name':'Kuldeep Yadav', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':3, 'overs':10, 'runs':34, 'field':0}
 bowling(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)    #passing dict as argument
```

Comment: `px` is not defined in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python can not access variables the way you think it does... (with `x=1` python will not be able to access `p1` when you write `px`; `px` is just a new name that has not been defined yet).

what you could do is this:

```
def bowling(*args):
    for px in args:
        print(px.get("role"))

bowling(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
```

i.e. use a variable number of arguments `*args` and iterate over them. you can find more information on how to use those in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) or [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) for example.

Comment: can you please send again this answer (with explaination)? .....because i am new to python.

Comment: added some links that may help.